# cppcheck complains dangerous use of c_str(). the value returned by c_str() is invalid after this call

Tags: c++, c++11, cppcheck

```
char* mstring(char str) {
    std::string mystring = "task:";
    mystring.append(str);
    return (*char)mystring.c_str();//dangerous use of c_str() the value returned by c_str() is invalid after this call
}
```

Comment: `mystring` is allocated on the stack and therefore goes out of scope when the function returns, taking `mystring.c_str()` with it.

Comment: Because it is local variable and you are trying to return local variable of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Cppcheck is correct. You are returning a pointer to a `char` that dies at the end of the function. Don't do that. Return a `std::string` instead which will be a copy that lives its own life (in the caller).

You want

```
std::string mstring(char ch) { 
    std::string mystring = "task:";
    mystring.append(ch);
    return mystring;
}
```

Comment: And if the compiler knows it can get away with it, there might not be any copying at all. The whole function might even go away. As long as the program behaviour is the same, the compiler can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @user4581301 I know. The "as if" rule and copy elision are beautiful things. But, *semantically* there's a copy, so I don't think my answer is wrong.

Comment: You know. They might not.